# Session is closed, on Hibernate 4.3

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I'm working over HIbernate 4.3 and I'm getting problems with sessions.. I'm trying to do some operations on database but didnt work properly. Im receiving the message that Session is closed.

My HibernateUtil class that create the session factory:

```
public class HibernateUtil
{
   private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory(); 
   private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
   {
      try
      {
         if (sessionFactory == null)
         {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
         }
         return sessionFactory;
      } catch (Throwable ex)
      {
         System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
      }
   }

   public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
   {
      return sessionFactory;
   }

   public static void shutdown()
   {
      getSessionFactory().close();
   }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>  
    <session-factory>  
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>  
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?autoReconnect=true</property>  
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>  
        <property name="connection.password">root</property> 

        <!-- Use the C3P0 connection pool. -->  
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">3</property>  
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">10</property>  
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>  

        <!-- Disable second-level cache. -->  
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>  
        <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>  
        <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts">false</property>  
        <property name="max_fetch_depth">3</property>  

        <!-- Print SQL to stdout. -->  
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>  
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>  

        <!-- Drop and then re-create schema on SessionFactory build, for testing. -->  
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>  

        <!-- Bind the getCurrentSession() method to the thread. -->  
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>  

        <mapping class="model.User"/>
        <mapping class="model.Point"/>
        <mapping class="model.Layer"/>
        <mapping class="model.AddressDatabase"/>

    </session-factory>  

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My HibernateListener that starts on the web.xml:

```
public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener {  
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {  
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();       
    }  
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {  
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }  
}
```

My DAOFactory of Hibernate:

```
public class HibernateDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {  
    public UserDao getUserDao() {  
        return (UserDao)instantiateDAO(UserDaoImpl.class);  
    }  

    private GenericHibernateDao instantiateDAO(Class daoClass) {  
        try {  
            GenericHibernateDao dao = (GenericHibernateDao)daoClass.newInstance();  
            dao.setSession(getCurrentSession());  
            return dao;  
        } catch (Exception ex) {  
            throw new RuntimeException("Can not instantiate DAO: " + daoClass, ex);  
        }  
    }  

    // You could override this if you don't want HibernateUtil for lookup  
    protected Session getCurrentSession() {  
        return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();  
    }      
}
```

And my HibernateDAO Factory, that instantiate the DAOs:

```
public class HibernateDAOFactory extends DAOFactory {  
     public UserDao getUserDao() {  
        return (UserDao)instantiateDAO(UserDaoImpl.class);  
    }  
    private GenericHibernateDao instantiateDAO(Class daoClass) {  
        try {  
            GenericHibernateDao dao = (GenericHibernateDao)daoClass.newInstance();  
            dao.setSession(getCurrentSession());t
            return dao;  
        } catch (Exception ex) {  
            throw new RuntimeException("Can not instantiate DAO: " + daoClass, ex);  
        }  
    }  
    protected Session getCurrentSession() {  
        return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();  
    }  

}
```

Relevant parts of GenericDAO:

```
public abstract class GenericHibernateDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, ID> {

    private Class<T> persistentClass;
    private Session session;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericHibernateDao() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public void setSession(Session s) {
        this.session = s;
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        if (session == null)
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        return session;
    }
    public T create(T entity) {
        getSession().save(entity);
        return entity;
    }
...
```

When I do sequences of operations on database I got the error.. The code below is a servlet and show how I instantiate my DAO and try to run some operations :

```
DAOFactory factory = DAOFactory.instance(DAOFactory.HIBERNATE);
userDao = factory.getUserDao();

Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction;

User user = new User();
user.setEmail("xxx@gmail.com");
user.setName("xxx");
user = userDao.create(user);
tx.commit(); <-- WORKS FINE

session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
tx = session.beginTransaction;
User user2 = userDao.findByEmail("xxx@gmail.com"); <-- HERE HAPPENS THE ERROR.
```

I followed theses tutorials:

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects

I tried to use OpenSesssion instead of getCurrentSession but I got this error on the first action on database:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: save is not valid without active transaction

And when I use the other one, I got the exception that the Sesssion is closed!

Any help will be appreciated.
Regards

Comment: What kind of error happens when you call `userDao.findByEmail` after `getCurrentSession()` ?

Comment: I'm sorry for inattention. You got exception that the Session is closed.

Comment: I got a exception there

Comment: The error you are getting looks like it's similar to a problem that I am having.  I think that when you commit a transaction this also causes the session to be closed so that when you start a new transaction with the same session an error is created.  I haven't worked out yet what I need to do to prevent this but I am trying to find where in my code a transaction could have been previously closed and the same session used to open a new transaction.  Could this be the same problem for you?